# Watir-Webdriver : take screenshot upon error/exception/fail. How to?

Tags: exception, error-handling, screenshot, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir-Webdriver. I have written a function to take the screenshot and it works fine. My problem is I need to call the method, upon any error/exception or fail happening during my testcase execution. I have googled it and couldn't find anything related. I have tried rescue block but it doesn't work for me. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

[Alister Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503158/alister-scott) has this about getting screenshots on [WatirMelon](http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/04/capturing-screenshots-in-watir-webdriver-cucumber/) when using cucumber:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    Dir::mkdir('screenshots') if not File.directory?('screenshots')
    screenshot = "./screenshots/FAILED_#{scenario.name.gsub(' ','_').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z_]/, '')}.png"
    Browser::BROWSER.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
    embed screenshot, 'image/png'
  end
end
```